# IBM Worklight - Accessing server properties in adapter JS?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I have to access few WL Server properties (from **worklight.properties**) in the **Adapter JS** file. I know we can access properties in the Adapter xml file but I have to access in the JS file.

```
{ WL.Server.configuration["local.IPAddress"] }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.

For example, using a newly created adapter,

1. I've added the following before the `return` in the `getStories()` function:

   ```
   WL.Logger.info("##################### Worklight protocal: " + WL.Server.configuration["publicWorkLightProtocol"]);
   ```
2. In order to see this log line in the Worklight Development Server's console in Eclipse, go to and change:

   - Servers view > server.xml > Logging section > Console log level >> INFO
3. `Run As > Deploy Worklight Adapter`
4. `Run As > Invoke Worklight Procedure`